# CMAKEList leap motion

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, leap-motion

I am trying to build a cmakelist file from makefile of leap motion, I can compile in a specific directory, I need to copy /include/ and /lib/x64/ directories . The makefile is the follow:

```
LEAP_LIBRARY := ./lib/x64/libLeap.so -Wl,-rpath,./lib/x64

Sample: Sample.cpp
    $(CXX) -Wall -g -I include Sample.cpp -o Sample $(LEAP_LIBRARY)
```

I have tried to build a cmakelist file as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Sample)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/include/)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/lib/x64/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g -I /include/ -Wl,-rpath,./lib/x64")

add_executable(Sample Sample.cpp )
target_link_libraries(Sample libLeap.so)
```

But I always get the same error:

```
Linking CXX executable Sample
/usr/bin/ld: can't find -lLeap
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Sample] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Sample.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: If you know *full path* to the library, use it in the *target_link_libraries* call: `target_link_libraries(Sample /lib/x64/libLeap.so)`. See also [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_link_libraries.html) for that command. Do not enumerate everything in the *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS* variable: `-I /include` directive is already transformed into `include_directories` command. As for RPATH directives, see [CMAKE RPATH handling wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve with following lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Sample)
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../include/)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(../lib/x64/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g")

add_executable(Sample Sample.cpp )
target_link_libraries(Sample -lLeap)
```

This solution has warnings but works:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:5 (LINK_DIRECTORIES):
This command specifies the relative path

../lib/x64

as a link directory.

Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the
source dir.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details.  Use the
cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files....
```

Two way to delete this warning:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(Sample)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../include/)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(lib/x64/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g")

add_executable(Sample Sample.cpp )
target_link_libraries(Sample -lLeap)
```

Or use `cmake .. -Wno-dev`

Comment: As it is written in the warning message, you should either use absolute path for `link_directories` or set property CMP0015 to NEW: `cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)`.